# Examples where English is "more Germanic" than German

Tags: germanic-languages

English is a so called a Germanic language, as are German, Yidish, Dutch, etc.

In a way it seems natural to believe that German is "more Germanic" than English. But here it is not clear what "more" is supposed to mean since "Germanic" is just a linguistic description of the inner working engine and the roots of a language.

In this context I am looking for examples that are "the other way around", i.e. where the original Germanic form is used in English and another (e.g. Roman) form in German.

The most prominent examples are the following ones:

> English: **window** from Germanic **Windloch** (wind hole)
>   German: **Fenster** from Latin **fenestra**

What would be a good source to help easily find (such described words)?

Comment: @Downvoter, Closevoter: What is wrong with this question? How can I improve it? Thank you!

Comment: You're asking for a full list of examples, lists, and articles. This is not constructive.

Comment: You're not asking for a single answer. You're asking for a list of examples. This, in itself, is not constructive. Either you ask for something in specific (in which case there is one answer), or you turn this into a community wiki (which can still be closed).

Comment: From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." Your question, you admit, asks for a list. This is open ended. This is off topic.

Comment: @simchona et al. (closers): I now this is off-topic because of the stated stipulated reasons, and I can see that many questions of this type can be very non-constructive and a detriment to this site...but...really...do you want to drive away a well thought out, scholarly, substantive question like this? It's not some frivolous joke or neologism list.

Comment: @simchona et al: would it be on opic if the OP changed it to 'What would be a good source to help easily find (such described words)?' ?

Comment: Is High German really considered the most 'central' of all Germanic languages, the least deviant from proto-Germanic? (I'm sure English is an outlier because of its large (native) influx from French, and academic neologisms from Latin and Greek.

Comment: @Mitch: Thank you, I just changed the question. Let's hope that enough people vote to reopen!

Comment: @vonjd 1/ voted to reopen. 2/ fenestra is even from Etruscan origin. 3/ Das Pferd (which most German believe is a pure Germanic word) actually comes from Latin "paraveredus".  The English "Horse" instead is from pure proto Germanic origin (*hursa).

Comment: One strategy: look for words in German that have non-Germanic etymology, then check the etymology of the corresponding English word. Checking etymology automatically on a list...I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I'll vote to reopen, but I can't speak for everyone

Comment: @vonjd: Would you be willing to have this be a community wiki? That way more people can participate, and it can allow for more subjective questions.

Comment: @simchona: I am primarily and foremostly interested in good answers to my question. So I would do whatever it takes: Changing the question, turning it into community wiki, etc.. How can I do that? Can you do it for me? Thank you!

Comment: @Vonjd: I flagged for a moderator to consider this for CW. At least in the past, there was a checkbox to automatically turn a question into CW when it was created, but they may have taken this feature out. And yes, I think that the community has started going against list questions more recently.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see a particularly good justification for why this question should be CW—please explain why the question is better with CW considering it is only asking for a place to look up such words.

Comment: @All: Do you know a good forum where I can ask this question? So that I don't bother you guys with this anymore?

Comment: @vonjd: I see all sorts of similar lists at wikipedia, but that's not really a very good discussion forum.